# A word for acting in advance of some expected or anticipated outcome

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

There's a word, I think that starts with a 'p', that describes doing something to solve a situation before it happens. For example, if a hurricane is approaching a store might take __ action to prepare for the flood of people that might come. In a fictional world, an organization might take __ action against crime based on some foreknowledge of a person's future actions.

**Edit**

It's not "preparatory", "precautionary", or "preventative".

Comment: *Pre-emptive*, perhaps?

Comment: Yes! Preemptive is the word I was looking for.

Comment: This reminds me of my question I asked almost in time with yours. I was wondering about a word to describe the act of positioning yourself as if to intercept a serve (in a racket sport). someone suggested "Jump on". I thought that described it well. Your phrasing of the question has led to interesting responses as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Preparatory* would describe an action you do to prepare for something else.

*Preventative* describes an action that can stop a problem from occurring.

*Preemptive* describes something you do before it is necessary, often as some kind of hedge against something that could occur in the future.

*Proactive* means to do things before they are absolutely necessary, but I wouldn't call anything a "proactive action". I might say somebody took a "proactive step" or something of that nature.

Comment: Proactive might be it, but I'm not sure. It doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: Preemptive is it. That's been bugging me for so long!

Comment: There's also *prophylactic* (in its "preventative" sense).

Answer (score 2):

Proactive might fit here as well. Rather than be reactive (after the fact) he was proactive (taking action before the fact).

Comment: Yeah. That's a good word too. That would definitely fit with the first sentence. I should have thought of a better sentence for describing preemptive.

Comment: Still valuable to think about. Love the process of honing my slightly rusty skills.

Answer (score 0):

### Precognitive

OP asks for "In a fictional world, an organization might take __ action against crime based on some foreknowledge of a person's future actions."

They are likely thinking, at least in part, of the film [Minority Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_Report_(film)).

> Minority Report is a 2002 American science fiction action film directed by Steven Spielberg, loosely based on the 1956 short story "The Minority Report" by Philip K. Dick. The film is set in Washington, D.C. and Northern Virginia in the year 2054, where Precrime, a specialized police department, apprehends criminals based on foreknowledge provided by three psychics called "precogs".

The organization Precrime would take 'precognitive action', preventing crimes through using their institutional knowledge of the future.  From its roots, 'precognitive' literally means foreknowledge.